# Laravel 8 - has many through table x or y

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a fresh jetstream installation. I created a model "Meeting" which has a foreign key team_id. I like to implement a relation from the User model to the Meeting model through the users team.

In jetstream the owner/creator of a team is listed in the team table and all members are listed in the pivot "team_user" table.

Now if I do something like:

```
public function meetings() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Meeting::class, Team::class);
}
```

this works for the team owner/creator...

And something like:

```
public function meetings() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Meeting::class, Membership::class, 'user_id', 'team_id', null, 'team_id');
}
```

works for members.

How can I make the relation that it works for creator and/or member (has many through Team or Membership)?

Comment: I would suggest adding the owner/creator to the team table. Otherwise you'd always have to run two queries to get the complete team. And resource-wise: the creator is also a member of the team/

Comment: Hi Douwe, thanks for your help! I think this is not the best database design of the jetstream team, cause I guess, many people will have the same issue. Why they dont put the team lead as a member?

Is it though technical possible to achieve a hasManyThrough relation through multiple tables?